# Solution structure with Repository, DAL, BAL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, architecture, repository

We would like to create a new project with a clean architecture. So our team decided to have:

- Repository pattern
- Data Access Layer
- Business Access Layer
- Common Layer (Abstractions such as IPersonRepository, IPersonService, ICSVExport)
- Some Core services such as create CSV files.
- UnitTests

Now what  we have is:

```
PersonsApp.Solution
--PersonsApp.WebUI
   -- Controllers (PersonController)
--PersonApp.Persistence
  --Core folder
      -IGenericRepository.cs (Abstraction)
      -IUnitOfWork.cs (Abstraction)
  --Infrastructure folder
      -DbDactory.cs (Implementation)
      -Disposable.cs (Implementation)
      -IDbFactory.cs (Abstraction)
      -RepositoryBase.cs (Abstraction)
  --Models folder
      - Here we DbContext, EF models (Implementation)
  --Repositories
      - PersonRepository.cs (Implementation)
--PersonApp.Service
  --Core folder
      -IPersonService.cs (Abstraction)
      -ICSVService.cs (Abstraction)
  --Business
      -PersonService.cs (Abstraction)     
  --System
      -CSVService.cs (Abstraction)
--PersonApp.Test
```

In my view, our structure is a little bit messy.

The first problem is:

- `PersonApp.Service` has abstractions(interfaces) and implementations
  in one class library.

The second problem is:

- `PersonApp.Persistence` has abstractions(`RepositoryBase`) and
  implementations in one class library. But if I move `RepositoryBase`,
  `IGenericRepository`, `IUnitOfWork` in a class library called
  `PersonApp.Abstractions`, then I will circular reference errors
  between `PersonApp.Abstractions` and `PersonApp.Persistence`

What is the best way to organize our solution?

Comment: Create new assembly, PersonApp.Common assembly, and move RepositoryBase, IGenericRepository, IUnitOfWork to it, then reference PersonApp.Common in PersonApp.Persistence and PersonApp.Abstractions. And don't let PersonApp.Common reference any of your other assemblies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably not a good S.O. question given it's asking something that is opinion-based. When planning out project structure I aim to keep things simple. If an abstraction is for polymorphism I will consider moving interfaces into a separate "common" assembly. For example if I want to provide several possible implementations of a thing, I will have a common assembly that declares the interface, then separate assemblies for the specific implementations.  In most cases I use interfaces as contracts so that I can substitute the real with mocks. In these cases I keep the interfaces nested beneath the concrete implementation. I use a VS add-in called NestIn to provide nesting support. This keeps the project structure nice and compact. However, a caveat, if you are using .Net Standard libraries, file nesting doesn't appear to be supported. (Hopefully this changes / has changed)

So for a SomeService, my folder project structure would look like:

- Services [folder]

  - SomeService.cs [concrete]

    - SomeService.dependencies.cs [partial] [nested]
    - ISomeService [nested]

the .dependencies.cs file is a partial class where I put all dependencies and the constructor. This keeps them tucked out of the way while I'm working on implementation. I used to rely on #regions way back, but frankly I cannot stand them now. Partial classes are much better IMO.

My repositories live alongside my entities in a Domain assembly.

- Entities [folder]

  - Configuration [folder]

    - OrderConfiguration.cs
  - Order.cs
- Repositories [folder]

  - OrderManagementRepository.cs

    - OrderManagementRepository.dependencies.cs
    - IOrderManagementRepository.cs
- MySystemDbContext.cs

I don't use Generic repositories, rather repositories are designed to pair up with Controllers or Services that they serve. I might have some general purpose repositories that service more than one consumer. (stuff like lookups, etc.) This pattern evolved for me from wanting to satisfy SRP. The biggest issue with things like generic repositories is that they need to serve multiple masters. While an OrderRepository might serve a single responsibility in being worried solely about Orders, the problem I see is that many different places will need access to Order information. This means different criteria, and wanting different amounts of data.  So instead, if I have an OrderManagementService that deals with orders, order lines, etc. and touches on Products and other bits and bobs in the process of placing orders, I will use an OrderManagementRepository to serve virtually all data needed by the service, and manage the wrapping of supported operations for managing an order. This means my service only typically needs 1 repository dependency (rather than an OrderRepository, ProductRepository, etc. etc. etc.) and my OrderManagemmentRepository has only 1 reason to change. (But that's getting off topic. :)

I started relying on Nesting a while ago back when you needed ReSharper or the like to get access to "Go to Implementation" for interfaces. Go to Definition would take you to the interfaces, which when in a separate namespace or assembly made navigating around dependencies a pain. By nesting interfaces under their concrete implementations, it's a quick click through from the interface to it's concrete implementation and back. I make use of tracking the current code file in the solution manager so as I navigate through code my project view highlights/expands to the currently viewed file.

Ultimately, your project structure should reflect how you prefer to navigate through the code to make it as intuitive and easy to get around to find the bits you need. That will be different for different people, so partial classes and nesting works really well for me, as I am a very visual person that uses the project view a lot. It might not serve any benefit for people that are hotkey navigation wizards.  Ultimately though I'd say keep it simple, and adaptable. Trying to plan it out too much in the early stages is like premature optimization. Don't be afraid to move things around as a project grows. A project that grows simply by adding code will invariably turn into a unstable, confusing tangled mess, no matter how well you try to plan ahead. Good code comes from constant re-factoring which is moving things around and deleting as well as adding. When your style is adaptable and you are building in a way that is constantly refining and code is getting better through natural selection, the structure is free to evolve.

Hopefully that might give some food for thought. Good luck in the green fields!

Edit: Regarding polymorphic interfaces vs. contract interfaces. With polymorphic interfaces where I want to have multiple, substitute-able concrete implementations, this is a case where the interface (and any applicable base class) would reside in a separate assembly. The nesting solution applies for cases where the only substitution is for mocking purposes. (unit testing) A recent example of a polymorphic instance was when I needed to replace an in-built SMS service wrapper to support a new SMS provider. This resulted in re-factoring a hard-coded concrete class from the original code into a SMSCore assembly containing the ISMSProvider interface and some general common definitions, then two assemblies for the implementations: SMSByMessageMedia and SMSBySoprano.

Other cases that come up might be around customizations. For instance I have a number of personal libraries and such for general purpose code, and when implementing them for a client there might be some client-specific "isms" that I want to make. These cases are typically resolved by extending the general purpose implementation (Open-Closed Principle) by overriding, or implementing a provided interface for the custom dependency that the general purpose code can consume. In both of these cases, the client project is going to have a reference to the concrete implementation(s) anyways, so having extendable classes and dependency interfaces in that assembly/namespace doesn't pose any issues. This saves needing to add several different namespaces & assembly references.

Comment: Thank you for so great answer! However, why do you store Abstraction (`ISomeService.cs`) in implementation `SomeService.cs`? What's the reason for that? In my view, if you want to implement your abstraction(`ISomeService.cs`) in the another assemby, then you will be need to add reference of your `ISomeService.cs` and `SomeService.cs`. Is it okay?

Comment: I've added an edit above to explain a couple scenarios around polymorphic interfaces where they'd normally be in a separate assembly, vs. other cases where I'd have them in the same assembly. (though possibly different namespaces)